# Error in rowSums(., na.rm = TRUE) : 'x' must be numeric - despite verifying variables are numeric

Tags: r, dataframe, numeric

When I tried summing 24 rows for specific columns in my data frame, it spit out

```
Error in rowSums(., na.rm = TRUE) : 'x' must be numeric
```

I tried various methods to determine whether the columns of interest were numeric.

```
x_isnum <- select_if(x2009, is.numeric)
names(x_isnum)
# Check data type of every variable in data frame
str(x2009)
```

All columns of interest were listed as numeric. Then I even opened the data frame and hovered over each column to verify they were numeric; they were.
I acknowledge that since the df is so large, it's possible I overlooked something. So I subset the data to learn about just the columns in question.

```
p = x2009[,c(48,49, 70:91)]
is.numeric(p)

FALSE
```

Since it returned false, I ran

```
str(p)

'data.frame':   17090 obs. of  24 variables:
 $ poss_cannabis_female_over_64 : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ poss_cannabis_female_under_10: num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ poss_cannabis_male_over_64   : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ poss_cannabis_male_under_10  : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ poss_cannabis_tot_10_12      : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ poss_cannabis_tot_13_14      : num  0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 ...
 $ poss_cannabis_tot_15         : num  0 1 0 3 0 0 0 1 0 0 ...
 $ poss_cannabis_tot_16         : num  1 0 3 2 1 0 2 2 2 1 ...
 $ poss_cannabis_tot_17         : num  1 0 1 3 1 2 0 3 2 1 ...
 $ poss_cannabis_tot_18         : num  0 0 1 2 2 1 1 1 0 0 ...
 $ poss_cannabis_tot_19         : num  0 2 0 4 1 0 3 0 0 0 ...
 $ poss_cannabis_tot_20         : num  0 1 0 2 0 0 2 1 1 3 ...
 $ poss_cannabis_tot_21         : num  0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 0 ...
 $ poss_cannabis_tot_22         : num  0 2 0 1 0 0 2 0 1 0 ...
 $ poss_cannabis_tot_23         : num  1 0 0 3 2 0 1 1 0 0 ...
 $ poss_cannabis_tot_24         : num  1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ poss_cannabis_tot_25_29      : num  0 0 2 3 2 1 0 0 1 2 ...
 $ poss_cannabis_tot_30_34      : num  0 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 ...
 $ poss_cannabis_tot_35_39      : num  1 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 0 ...
 $ poss_cannabis_tot_40_44      : num  0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 ...
 $ poss_cannabis_tot_45_49      : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ poss_cannabis_tot_50_54      : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ poss_cannabis_tot_55_59      : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ poss_cannabis_tot_60_64      : num  0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 ...
```

I also ran

```
sapply(p, is.numeric)

poss_cannabis_female_over_64 
                         TRUE 
poss_cannabis_female_under_10 
                         TRUE 
   poss_cannabis_male_over_64 
                         TRUE 
  poss_cannabis_male_under_10 
                         TRUE 
      poss_cannabis_tot_10_12 
                         TRUE 
      poss_cannabis_tot_13_14 
                         TRUE 
         poss_cannabis_tot_15 
                         TRUE 
         poss_cannabis_tot_16 
                         TRUE 
         poss_cannabis_tot_17 
                         TRUE 
         poss_cannabis_tot_18 
                         TRUE 
         poss_cannabis_tot_19 
                         TRUE 
         poss_cannabis_tot_20 
                         TRUE 
         poss_cannabis_tot_21 
                         TRUE 
         poss_cannabis_tot_22 
                         TRUE 
         poss_cannabis_tot_23 
                         TRUE 
         poss_cannabis_tot_24 
                         TRUE 
      poss_cannabis_tot_25_29 
                         TRUE 
      poss_cannabis_tot_30_34 
                         TRUE 
      poss_cannabis_tot_35_39 
                         TRUE 
      poss_cannabis_tot_40_44 
                         TRUE 
      poss_cannabis_tot_45_49 
                         TRUE 
      poss_cannabis_tot_50_54 
                         TRUE 
      poss_cannabis_tot_55_59 
                         TRUE 
      poss_cannabis_tot_60_64 
                         TRUE
```

Finally, I ran `sapply(p, class)`, which again displayed numeric for each variable. I again hovered over each column in the subsetted data frame, and again, each column said it was numeric

There must be something I am missing if r is telling me it's not numeric. I doubt the code is the problem because I ran it on a smaller, made up df with no issues, but just in case, here is what I ran to sum the rows of specific columns.

```
x2009 = x2009 %>%
  mutate(poss_cannabis_juv_tot = select(., c(49,71:76))) %>% 
  rowSums(na.rm = TRUE) %>% 
  mutate(poss_cannabis_adult_tot = select(., c(48,70,77:91))) %>%
  rowSums(na.rm = TRUE) %>% 
  relocate(poss_cannabis_juv_tot, .after = poss_cannabis_male_17) %>% 
  relocate(poss_cannabis_adult_tot, .after = poss_cannabis_male_over_64)
```

What is going on??

Comment: `is.numeric` expects a vector and not a data.frame

Comment: @akrun What would you use for a data frame?

Comment: For a data.frame the unit is a column (it is actually a list with elements i.e. columns of equal length).  So we need to loop over the columns i.e. `sapply(x2009, is.numeric)`

Comment: @akrun Is there one that is similar to ```is.numeric()``` in that it just tells you whether the whole df is numeric?

Comment: if you want to get some summary information. you can use `skimr::skim(iris)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is in creating a column from from `select`.  Instead, select the columns within `across` and get the `rowSums`

```
library(dplyr)
x2009 %>%
    mutate(poss_cannabis_juv_tot = rowSums(across(where(is.numeric)), 
        na.rm = TRUE))
```

Or if it should be with indexes

```
x2009 %>%
    mutate(poss_cannabis_juv_tot = rowSums(across(c(49,71:76)), na.rm = TRUE),
     poss_cannabis_adult_tot = rowSums(across(c(48,70,77:91)), na.rm = TRUE)) %>%
    relocate(poss_cannabis_juv_tot, .after = poss_cannabis_male_17) %>% 
    relocate(poss_cannabis_adult_tot, .after = poss_cannabis_male_over_64)
```

---

In the OP's code, the `rowSums` part is selecting all the columns because the column created with `select` is a `data.frame` (in addition to the other non-numeric columns)

```
> head(iris) %>%
    mutate(new = select(., 2:4)) %>%
    str
'data.frame':   6 obs. of  6 variables:
 $ Sepal.Length: num  5.1 4.9 4.7 4.6 5 5.4
 $ Sepal.Width : num  3.5 3 3.2 3.1 3.6 3.9
 $ Petal.Length: num  1.4 1.4 1.3 1.5 1.4 1.7
 $ Petal.Width : num  0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.4
 $ Species     : Factor w/ 3 levels "setosa","versicolor",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1
 $ new         :'data.frame':   6 obs. of  3 variables:
  ..$ Sepal.Width : num  3.5 3 3.2 3.1 3.6 3.9
  ..$ Petal.Length: num  1.4 1.4 1.3 1.5 1.4 1.7
  ..$ Petal.Width : num  0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.4

head(iris) %>% 
   mutate(new = select(., 2:4)) %>%
  rowSums(na.rm = TRUE)
Error in rowSums(., na.rm = TRUE) : 'x' must be numeric
```

Instead, with `across`

```
head(iris) %>%
    mutate(new = rowSums(across(2:4), na.rm = TRUE))
 Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species new
1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa 5.1
2          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa 4.6
3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa 4.7
4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa 4.8
5          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2  setosa 5.2
6          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4  setosa 6.0
```

Comment: Perfect! The one with the indexes is exactly the one that worked! Could you please elaborate on why ```select``` is the issue? I just want to make sure I know when and when not to use select in the future.

Comment: Also, would
```x2009 %>%
    mutate(poss_cannabis_juv_tot = rowSums(across(where(is.numeric)), 
        na.rm = TRUE))```
give the sum across the entire row?

Comment: @bandcar for the second question, yes, it selects all numeric columns, and gets the sum across the entire subset of numeric columns.   Regarding the issue with select.  It is not the select perse.  You can still use `select` i.e. but when you create a data.frame column `poss_cannabis_juv_tot` in the previous mutate, you have to extract that column in the next step to do `rowSums` i.e. `rowSums(.$poss_cannabis_juv_tot)`